# How to search side Menu list using jquery/javascript after input?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have input filed in top of Menu that i want to search list of menu inside all a anchor tag.
I tried a lot but not able to achieve required output. Any one there to help me.

I want to display only all the anchor tag. If the input field is empty the menu should be ni normal state.

```
<nav class="navbar-default" role="navigation" style="overflow: hidden; width: auto; height: 691px;">
<div class="sidebar-collapse">
    <ul class="nav" id="side-menu">
        <li>
            <input type="text" id="txt_search" class="form-control ui-front" placeholder="Search Menu..." autocomplete="off" onkeyup="searchAppMenus();">
        </li>
            <li class="special_link_pos">
                <a>FOOD</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-child">
                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-wrench"></i> <span class="nav-label">SET UP</span><span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
                <ul class="nav nav-second-level collapse">
                        <li class="nav-subchild">
                            <a> <i class="far fa-circle nav-icon"></i>Menu Header</a>
                        </li>
                     
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-child">
                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-copy"></i> <span class="nav-label">TRANSACTION</span><span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
                <ul class="nav nav-second-level collapse">
                        <li class="nav-subchild">
                            <a> <i class="far fa-circle nav-icon"></i>Sales</a>
                        </li> 
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-child">
                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-clipboard-check"></i> <span class="nav-label">REPORT</span><span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
                <ul class="nav nav-second-level collapse">
                        <li class="nav-subchild">
                            <a> <i class="far fa-circle nav-icon"></i>Shift Handover</a>
                        </li>
                       
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-child">
                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-clipboard-check"></i> <span class="nav-label">REPORT</span><span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
                <ul class="nav nav-second-level collapse">
                        <li class="nav-subchild">
                            <a class="nav-link" onclick="go(this);">
                                <i class="far fa-circle nav-icon"></i>Accounting Report

                                    <span class="fa fa-arrow-down"></span>
                            </a>
                                <ul class="nav nav-third-level collapse">
                                    <li>
                                        <a class="nav-link" onclick="go(this);">
                                            <i class="far fa-dot-circle nav-icon"></i>
                                            Profit and Loss
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                    
                                </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-subchild">
                            <a class="nav-link" onclick="go(this);">
                                <i class="far fa-circle nav-icon"></i>Accounting Ledgers
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="special_link_misc">
                <a>MISCELLANEOUS</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-child">
                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-cog"></i> <span class="nav-label">GENERAL</span><span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
                <ul class="nav nav-second-level collapse">
                        <li class="nav-subchild">
                            <a onclick="go(this);"> <i class="far fa-circle nav-icon"></i>Group Right</a>
                        </li>
                       
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-child">
                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-cog"></i> <span class="nav-label">UTILITY</span><span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
                <ul class="nav nav-second-level collapse">
                        <li class="nav-subchild">
                            <a onclick="go(this);"> <i class="far fa-circle nav-icon"></i>Company</a>
                        </li>
                       
                </ul>
            </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

```
<script>
 function searchAppmenus() {
    var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
    input = document.getElementById("txt_search");
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    ul = document.getElementsByClassName("nav");
    li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");
    for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
        a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
        if (a.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
            li[i].style.display = "";
        } else {
            li[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}
```

This code is not working. what's wrong with this code.
Please anyone there to Solve this..

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following.

```js
$(function() {
  function filterMenu(term) {
    var filter, input = term.toUpperCase();
    $(".nav a").each(function(i, el) {
      filter = $(el).text().toUpperCase();
      if (filter.indexOf(input) < 0) {
        $(el).parent().hide();
      }
    });
  }

  $("#txt_search").keyup(function(event) {
    // Show all Items
    $(".nav li").show();
    // If Empty, do nothing
    if ($(this).val() !== "") {
      // Filter out items that do not match
      filterMenu($(this).val());
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="navbar-default" role="navigation" style="overflow: hidden; width: auto; height: 691px;">
  <div class="sidebar-collapse">
    <ul class="nav" id="side-menu">
      <li>
        <input type="text" id="txt_search" class="form-control ui-front" placeholder="Search Menu..." autocomplete="off">
      </li>
      <li class="special_link_pos">
        <a>FOOD</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-child">
        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-wrench"></i> <span class="nav-label">SET UP</span><span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
        <ul class="nav nav-second-level collapse">
          <li class="nav-subchild">
            <a> <i class="far fa-circle nav-icon"></i>Menu Header</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-child">
        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-copy"></i> <span class="nav-label">TRANSACTION</span><span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
        <ul class="nav nav-second-level collapse">
          <li class="nav-subchild">
            <a> <i class="far fa-circle nav-icon"></i>Sales</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-child">
        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-clipboard-check"></i> <span class="nav-label">REPORT</span><span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
        <ul class="nav nav-second-level collapse">
          <li class="nav-subchild">
            <a> <i class="far fa-circle nav-icon"></i>Shift Handover</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-child">
        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-clipboard-check"></i> <span class="nav-label">REPORT</span><span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
        <ul class="nav nav-second-level collapse">
          <li class="nav-subchild">
            <a class="nav-link" onclick="go(this);">
              <i class="far fa-circle nav-icon"></i>Accounting Report
              <span class="fa fa-arrow-down"></span>
            </a>
            <ul class="nav nav-third-level collapse">
              <li>
                <a class="nav-link" onclick="go(this);">
                  <i class="far fa-dot-circle nav-icon"></i> Profit and Loss
                </a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-subchild">
            <a class="nav-link" onclick="go(this);">
              <i class="far fa-circle nav-icon"></i>Accounting Ledgers
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="special_link_misc">
        <a>MISCELLANEOUS</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-child">
        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-cog"></i> <span class="nav-label">GENERAL</span><span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
        <ul class="nav nav-second-level collapse">
          <li class="nav-subchild">
            <a onclick="go(this);"> <i class="far fa-circle nav-icon"></i>Group Right</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-child">
        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-cog"></i> <span class="nav-label">UTILITY</span><span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
        <ul class="nav nav-second-level collapse">
          <li class="nav-subchild">
            <a onclick="go(this);"> <i class="far fa-circle nav-icon"></i>Company</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

This answer is offered in jQuery. It iterates all the anchors and looks for the term in the text of the item. If it's not found, it is hidden.